# Why does Windows prompt me to grant admin permission when I am already connected as an admin?

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have a remote session going on Windows Server 2019. I am logged in as a user who is a member of the local Administrators on the server. When I try to copy a folder I get the message:
[image]

If I click Continue it goes ahead with the copy. There are other servers I work with where I don't see this behavior.

Why is Windows prompting me this way? Is there a server wide setting that controls this?

Comment: That's a function of User Account Control.

Comment: @joeqwerty I checked UAC on this server. The slider in the UAC settings is currently set to **Never Notify**. It doesn't seem like I should be seeing the prompts if the setting in **Never Notify**.

Comment: @joeqwerty According to this [article](https://pchawda.wordpress.com/2019/01/17/disabling-user-account-control-uac-on-windows-server/) the UAC setting in the Control Panel doesn't always work, so the setting must be changed in the Windows Registry. After following those steps and restarting the server I am no longer prompted to continue when I copy files on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joeqwerty wrote, that's a function of User Account Control (UAC), which has been part of Windows increased security posture since the Windows Server 2008/Windows Vista days.

Yes, [there are server-wide settings to turn off UAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/disable-user-account-control), and no, you usually shouldn't do that: The system is not without faults but it protects you from a number of categories of user error and malicious software behavior. Change your habits to work within the intentions of the system instead.

Comment: I had to force the system to turn off UAC using the registry. You make a good point about working with the intensions of the system. The article you cite has some good information about that.